# Travis CI build exited with 1, test failed.. working on windows

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, travis-ci

I am trying to setup a development environment. I am using Windows, I try to run units tests using mocha and run the program, it works fine. When I try to do CI in Travis CI, I get the following error:

> "Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern:
>   buildScripts/testsetup.js"

Where my code in package.json looks like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start:config": "babel-node buildscripts/srcserver.js",
     "start": "npm-run-all --parallel start:config test",
    "test" : "mocha --reporter progress buildScripts/testsetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\""
}
```

It seems like in travis, it doesn't see buildscripts/testsetup.js as the config for the tests, but it sees it as if it must contain test code.

Here's my repo on github for if you need to take a look at the code: 
https://github.com/derhallim/testenv

I tried to run the build on Appveyor, and it worked fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Any idea anyone?